# The autorun.exe and setup.exe dont startup on windows 8, how can i make it work

Tags: windows-8

im trying to install a game by an .iso file. I mounted this file in Daemon tools lite but nothing happend. So i went to the directory and manually clicked first the Autorun.exe and lateron the setup.exe, both did not do anything. They do not show in my taskmanager or start up at all.

Can someone help me?

I work with a windows 8.1 laptop, with the required stats for the game, so this should not give a problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include contents of `autorun.inf`. (indent it with 4 spaces to use some nice formatting)

Comment: Are you sure the ISO is OK? Have you tried creating/downloading it again?  Is the program known to be compatible with Windows 8?  Have you tried using the compatibility modes yet?

Comment: .iso is okay, i tried indeed all possible compatibel modes. All autorun.inf says is : [autorun]
open=Autorun.exe
icon=Sims3.ico

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 can mount .iso's native, have you tried using it?  Right click on the image and choose mount image.  I would also "eject" or dismount all images and other cds from the system before mounting again.